# Most useful Python modules from the standard library?

Tags: python, module, standard-library

I am teaching a graduate level Python class at the University of Paris, and the students need to be introduced to the standard library.  I want to discuss with them about some of the most important standard modules.

What modules do you think are absolute musts?  Even though responses probably vary depending on your field (web programming, science, etc.), I feel that some modules are commonly needed: `math`, `sys`, `re`, `os`, `os.path`, `logging`,… and maybe: `collections`, `struct`,…

What modules would you suggest I present, in a 1 or 2 hour slot?

Comment: import antigravity: http://xkcd.com/353/ 

... your wish is my command Clement ;)

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: should change the title to 'Most useful Python standard lib module' and check the spelling of some words :-)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453574/programming-libraries

Comment: @ S.Lott: you're right!  Hence the importance of using tags: the other question (posted 1 hour before mine!) has no tags, and I did not find it when asking the question of this thread…

Comment: @dalloliogm: title changed!  Thanks!

Comment: graduate class in Python ?! weird

Comment: @Eli: I wish I was teaching first-year students, as they would learn more efficiently how to program (they unfortunately learn C or Fortran first).

Comment: Check this out: http://abhilashshukla.com/programming/50-python-libraries-add-ons-programmers-live-without/ could get you close

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Modules to cover in a 1-2 hour slot entirely depend on your audience's interest or focus.  What other classes are they taking?  What are they prepared to make use of immediately?

Be sure to mention `math`, `decimal` and `datetime` and `time` and `re`.

For IT-types who will be doing file-oriented work: `glob`, `fnmatch`, `os`, `os.path`, `tempfile`, and `shutil`.

Database folks must hear about `sqlite` and `json`.

Simulation audience may want to hear about `random`.

Web developers must hear about `urllib2` from a client point of view.  Also Beautiful Soup and an XML parser of your choice.

Web developers must hear about `logging` and `wsgiref` from a server point of view.

Comment: +1 for being the first to add shutil!

Comment: Beautiful Soup is a bit broken of late. You may want to recommend lxml instead. It handles HTML as well as XML. Ian Bicking has a good article on this. http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/

Answer (score 33):

I'd offer `itertools` and `functools`. These modules operate over abstractions that are found everywhere in programming, so I think they are useful to study. Among more practical things, xml modules (`xml.dom`, `xml.sax`) can be very useful.

Comment: +1 itertools. For XML, `xml.etree.ElementTree` is *really* friendly.

Comment: yup, +1 for `itertools` and `functools`

Comment: +1 for itertools, functools is great if you are using newish python. It's good functional style that smart students should know.

Comment: +1 `itertools`. I think that `collections` also fits in that definition of modules with a very broad scope.

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at [PyMOTW](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/contents.html) (Python Module Of The Week). Although it is not strictly stdlib, it's a great resource of obvious and not so obvious gems of the python stdlib. What's more, it also serves as excellent documentation of the introduced modules.

Comment: Yeah, I love PyMOTW!  I had not thought of checking it, though: thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for a few modules which make the most sense to a typical computer user/programmer performing typical computer tasks. That way, there's the largest chance that they might actually **use** python on their own time.

In my opinion, the operations most people will likely perform are file operations, for example going over every file in a directory and performing some action on it.

Therefore, I'd say the modules: **os and os.path** are probably the most important, and also mention **glob, fnmatch and shutil**. Also, **subprocess** might be very useful too, since it tends to get used in the above mentioned context.

Lastly, I'd go with **optparse**, since that will get them into very quickly making usable, programmer-friendly programs, which hopefully will also encourage them to actually write programs that other people want to use.

Comment: +1 for mentioning optparse for the first time in this thread!

Comment: optparse is deprecated. argparse made it into the standard library as a replacement. Though, I think docopt is an even better alternative: http://docopt.org/

Answer (score 7):

I just remember a very practical module: copy.
I use the deepcopy() from it quite often.

Comment: +1: This had not been mentioned.  Good catch!

Comment: +1 copy , i've use deepcopy to fix a stupid bug.

Answer (score 6):

It depends a little on what they will be doing and what level they are.
Some modules I wish someone pointed out to me when I started are:

- StringIO - to stop them from reimplementing it, which they will if they don't discover it.
- logging - to put them on the right path when it comes to debug printouts
- pickle - to stop them from trying to use XML everywhere.
- xml.etree.ElementTree - To save them from the DOM model when they actually need to work with XML.
- pprint - to make nested structures in python less intimidating.

Comment: +1 for adding pprint to the modules already mentioned!

Answer (score 5):

I would add urllib2 to the list.

Answer (score 5):

In only a one-two hour slot, I would introduce [easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall) and the [PyPI repository](http://pypi.python.org/pypi): even if they are not in the standard lib, they enable you to install many other external modules, and it is the first place where to look when you can't find in the standard lib.

Apart from that, I would introduce numpy, re, doctest/unittest, and maybe pickle.

Comment: +1 for pickle -> comes in handy all the time

Answer (score 4):

`operator`, next to what's already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about datetime, weakref, pickle, StringIO, heapq, may be threading.

And numpy also worths mentioning, although it is not from the standard library.

Comment: +1 for heapq... it's a super-fun class which most folks will never discover by themselves. It's of great importance for algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

os and os.path: because those are the core modules which anyone will require to write platform independent code in python and students can switch from shell script to python script after learning os and os.path.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone here got all the important ones, except for `sys`.  If you look at actual Python code, `sys` is probably one of the most commonly used modules (usually because of `sys.version`).

Also, it's not really a module, but I would mention `__future__`.

And nobody should use Python without doing `import this`.

Comment: +1 for `__future__`!  I *did* mention `sys` in the original post. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from those you mentioned, I found subprocess and sqlite3 modules particularly useful. But I would certainly advice to students to take a look at the list of standard library modules themselves. Also, from modules outside of standard library, I would mention numpy (or numarray) and pyparsing.

Comment: Yeah, they're science students.  Part of the class is devoted to Numpy/Scipy/Matplotlib.  I'll check pyparsing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd place some weight on the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module.  If they are beginners at programming, they certainly won't be aware of the implications of [floating point accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).  The `decimal` module is extremely valuable if working with currency or other units that must retain exact decimal precision through several mathematic operations.

Of course, you'd probably want to touch on situations when you  *don't* need to be that accurate as well.

Answer (score 1):

For science student, a rarely heard but powerful module 'networkx' will be valuable. But they need to install it first. This module is well documented: http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html

Comment: Interesting module, but the question is about the *standard* library. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to live without [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)

```
>>> # Python shell usage
... import timeit
>>> tt = timeit.Timer("foo = 'time this'", "print 'setup with this arg'")
>>> tt.timeit(number=1000)
setup with this arg
0.00021100044250488281
>>>

[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ # Bash shell usage
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ # 5 runs with 1000 samples each.
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ python -m timeit -n 1000 -r 5 -s "print 'setup w/ this arg'" \
    "foo = 'time this'"
setup w/ this arg
setup w/ this arg
setup w/ this arg
setup w/ this arg
setup w/ this arg
1000 loops, best of 5: 0.173 usec per loop
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```